# Reg Expression Formula-Extract all text matching pattern

Tags: formula, netsuite

I have the following Regexp substring in a formula field for a Netsuite workflow:

```
 REGEXP_SUBSTR({title},'[S][0-9]+')
```

This works correctly if there is a string such as S1223548 in the {title} field.

However, if the title field has a string like the following,
FW: Invoice 1545478,S121548

I receive an "ERROR: Invalid Expression" error message.

Why is that? Shouldn't this be searching for the pattern of the letter S and then numbers regardless of where that string pattern is? i.e. at the start of the text string or in the middle

EDIT: Full formula being used:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it should work as you're expecting.  I tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR('FW: Invoice 1545478,S121548','[S][0-9]+')` and got "S121548" returned as expected.  Make sure you're using `Formula (Text)`, and check there aren't special characters in the title field.  If you have multiple results returned, do you see some with the expected answer and others with "ERROR: Invalid Expression" in the same result set?  If so share a screenshot of the results.

Comment: Thanks Kryption. I tried the formula right now in a demo account (per the edit) and it worked perfectly. I think you are right that it is probably due to special characters
I will have another look at the actual account and post my findings here. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @Krypton for your help with this. I found the cause of the issue and it was not related to the regexp formula as you correctly pointed out. The formula in the workflow was referring to the 'title' field which only exists after submit. The original regexp formula was looking at the incoming messages field in a before submit workflow action so didn't have the issue of not being able to find a matching string. I would have wasted time rewriting the formula before I saw your answer